# build not working in linux with netbeans project

Tags: java, linux, ant, netbeans-7

I have written a java web application(deployed on glassfish server) to deploy on to Tomcat server. I copied the project file along with build.xml to a linux system and tried

```
[packwolf src]$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/packwolf/Application/src/build.xml:12: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/packwolf/Application/src/nbproject/build-impl.xml:22: Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Not doesn't support the nested "antversion" element.
```

The web application is supposed to be portable, but it isn't. Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your ant version. It might not be the same as on your other box.